# Recovering from magic gear-destroying hazards or opponents?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

During one of my pathfinder sessions, my group came across a [Rust Monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/rust-monster/), this encounter, while not that dangerous in itself, successfully destroyed one of my player's Armor.

This proved to be mostly a temporary inconvinience as the armor wasn't too costly to replace. But it did make me think about PC's gear destruction.

When a NPC steals an item from the group, it's likely that there is a way for them to get it back and it can be a great way to start a plot.

But when something is destroyed (not just broken), you can't get it back. Unless you buy a similar item but it's still not the same thing and it will cost you.

Nonetheless, the threat of losing or damaging gear is an interesting one and I'd like to be able to use it to it's full extent. (Making gear unusable)

As I understand that the permanent destruction or rare or costly magic items can really anger players, I'd like to be able to find a way for them to repair even the most powerful items, given some time and maybe a small amount of ressources.

So here lies my question :

**Are there any rules, spells or skills that player can use to repair, reform or remake destroyed magic items ? (preferably not too costly, difficult or rare)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming it is magic armor, the [*make whole*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/make-whole/) spell is what you are looking for. If it is not magical, you can just use the [*mending*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mending/) cantrip. On the other hand, if it’s a high-level magic item, [*greater make whole*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/make-whole/#TOC-Make-Whole-Greater) may be more desirable, as *make whole* can only affect items with a caster level less than half your level, while *greater make whole* can fix items with a caster level up to your whole level.

Comment: I didn't realize how low of a spell level Make Whole is... learn something new I guess. And it even specifically calls out destroyed equipment being covered

Comment: @Ifusaso Same, actually. I thought *make whole* was like 4th level, and couldn’t fix destroyed magic items.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that characters can use item crafting feats to repair magic items, too (doing so takes half the time and money that crafting the item would). - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Damaging-Magic-Items

Comment: @minnmass That’s only for damaged-but-not-destroyed items. I mean, I think. [The item-repair rules are a mess.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95568/4563)

Comment: Might be worth it to mention that your caster level has to be twice that of what you're repairing.  Quite the limitation!

Comment: That's new the *Pathfinder* version of the spell [*make whole*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#make-whole) (that's the more limited *3.5e* version). It used to be you'd take the broken parts to an item creator, like somebody who has the feat [Craft Magic Arms and Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-magic-arms-and-armor-item-creation-final/), because that dude "can also mend a broken magic weapon, suit of armor, or shield if it is one that [he] could make. Doing so costs half the raw materials and half the time it would take to craft that item in the first place."

Comment: Greater Make Whole is only a 4th level spell (available around level 7) and allows you to repair up to your CL instead of 1/2... for when your really nice item breaks.